# Use Apache Daffodil cmd interface

Tags: cmd, dfdl

I am new to Apache Daffodil and am trying to follow the example provided: https://daffodil.apache.org/examples/

I am trying to parse the file, simpleCSV using the schema, csv.dfdl.xsd. Both files are in the same folder as the daffodil.bat folder.

In cmd, I run `.\daffodil.bat parse --schema csv.dfdl.xsd simpleCSV.csv`

I get the error:

```
[error] Schema Definition Error: Error loading schema due to org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; DaffodilXMLLoader: Unable to resolve schemaLocation='csv-base-format.dfdl.xsd'.
Schema context: file:/C:/Users/rinat/OneDrive/Desktop/WORK%20STUFF/apache-daffodil-3.4.0-bin/apache-daffodil-3.4.0-bin/bin/csv.dfdl.xsd Location in file:/C:/Users/rinat/OneDrive/Desktop/WORK STUFF/apache-daffodil-3.4.0-bin/apache-daffodil-3.4.0-bin/bin/csv.dfdl.xsd`
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy `csv-base-format.dfdl.xsd` (found in the same `src/` directory as `csv.dfdl.xsd`) into the same directory as your `csv.dfdl.xsd` file. That file provides a number of default settings imported by `csv.dfdl.xsd`, so they must be in the same directory.